# Get the current color of the status bar

Tags: ios, uistatusbar

Is it possible to get the current color of the status bar in iOS? I know we can change the color but is it possible to programmatically get the current state of the status bar? e.g whether its `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` or `UIStatusBarStyleDefault`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it like this:

```
UIStatusBarStyle currentStyle = [UIApplication sharedAppplication].statusBarStyle;
```

Comment: Good answer. Just incase any body is interested the return time is an NSInteger.